# Store in database description with numeric value

Tags: php, mysql, database, reactjs

I have this kind of text as "description" but some values are numeric and must be changed based on a ratio. I was wondering on how to properly store that in database.

"- Add 49 things in my 7 bags"

My initial idea was to do that :

```
+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------------+-----------+
| part1 | num1 |     part2     | num2 |  part3  |  rationum1 | rationum2 |
+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------------+-----------+
| - Add |   49 | things  in my |    7 |    bags |        1.3 |       1.2 |
+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

It seems however very inefficient. Plus, I want to add a tooltip on some things. For example, "-Add" must have a tooltip linked but I don't know how to apply a property on only one part of the table.

Any advices would be welcome!

EDIT : I'm using PHP to fetch data as JSON, and then I'm using JavaScript (React) for the display.

Comment: Why don't you use `VARCHAR` as the data type? see this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp)

Comment: _"Plus, I want to add a tooltip on some things."_ Then please do mention your server side language and how you fetch your data and display it.

Comment: I'm using PHP to fetch data as JSON, and then I'm using JavaScript (React) for the display.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your proposed table layout. It's not inefficient either.  MySql is built for this. It can handle millions of rows of this kind of thing without breaking a sweat.

Do add an autoincrementing `id` value to each row, to use as a primary key. You may wish to consider adding a timestamp column too.

Define your num1 and num2 columns as `int`, or if you need fractional values, as `double`. (Javascript treats all numbers as double).

Define your fractional columns as `double`.

Define your textual columns as `varchar(250)` or some such thing, and add a textual column for your tooltip's text.

And, you're done.

**But** when I look at your example **Add 49 things in my 7 bags** I see more meaning than just a phrase.

- a verb: **Add**.
- a source_count:  **49**
- a source description: **things**.
- a preposition:  **in**
- a possessive: **my**
- a target_count: **7**
- a target_description: **bags**

Does your system also need to say **Steal 5 grenades from Joe's 2 ammo cases**  or some such thing (I'm assuming you are making some kind of game)?

If so, you may want a more elaborate set of table layouts taking into account the parts of the phrase.  Then your query can use appropriate JOIN operations.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You had a good intuition because I will have other sentences not really linked to this one and kind of different but still repeating at least this pattern : "text" number "text" ...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps normalize it.

F.e. put the descriptions with placeholders in another table, together with the tooltip.

Then put a foreign key in the table with the items.

Example code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tst_stuff;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tst_stufftodo;

CREATE TABLE tst_stufftodo (id int primary key auto_increment, description varchar(100), tooltip varchar(1000));

CREATE TABLE tst_stuff (id int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(100), num1 int not null default 0, num2 int not null default 0, rationum1 decimal(4,1) not null default 0, rationum2 decimal(4,1) not null default 0, 
std_id int,
FOREIGN KEY (std_id) REFERENCES stufftodo(id)
);

INSERT INTO tst_stufftodo (description, tooltip)
VALUES 
('Add &num1& things in my &num2& &name&', 'Add the stuff');

INSERT INTO tst_stuff (name, num1, num2, rationum1, rationum2, std_id) VALUES
('bags', 49, 7, 1.2, 1.3, 1),
('socks', 1000000, 2, 0.5, 0.6, 1);

select s.id, replace(replace(replace(std.description,'&name&',s.name), '&num1&',s.num1), '&num2&',s.num2) as description
from tst_stuff s
join tst_stufftodo std on std.id = s.std_id;
```

Result:

```
id  description
1   Add 49 things in my 7 bags
2   Add 1000000 things in my 2 socks
```

But it's probably better to do the replacement of the placeholders in the PHP presentation layer.